# Where does this SSMS context menu option to script data come from?

Tags: ssms

The image below shows the context menu I'm asking about. I've had it in SSMS 2008 R2 for so long I thought it was a feature of SSMS. Today I'm working with two other developers and it turns out they do not have this nice little feature, in fact they've never seen it. So now we are wondering where it came from. Is it an add-in? Is it turned on by some obscure feature? 
[image: SSMS script data as context menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a feature not supported by Microsoft. It is an Addin for SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: I just discovered the plugin I'm using can't handle single quotes, as you mention. This plugin does cost $10 though.

Comment: That said, I've just discovered SSMS 2008 natively supports the export of data as SQL (with quotes properly escaped): Right click DB > Tasks > Generate Scripts... > Next > Set 'Script Data' to 'True' > etc > etc